# Adding my iphone app as a content menu in the device

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to install my iPhone app as shortcut.
If a user long-touches an image in an email attachment, this option should appear along with **“Print”**, **“Save to camera roll”**, **“Facebook”**, **“Twitter”** etc.
 Can anyone help me with this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to open the file of type .png,.jpeg or .pg, you must list Document type Key in Info.plist of your file as shown below:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>files</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>.png</string>
                <string>.jpegf</string>
                <string>.jpg</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Refer:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: Where should I add this in the info.plist. Inside the information property list?

Comment: YEs.. open your .plist as Source Code and add it.. tell me if it works..

Comment: Everything is perfect. I added the same code. Still not working. But i cannot find my app icon when i long press the images.